# builds run fine, but got crash when run?

Tags: c++, build, crash

im still learning about ADT, i have multy linked listed code from myself, but my coding get crash, can anyone tell me where im wrong?
my program is input laptop brand then input the type from the brand.

```
#ifndef SISWA_H_INCLUDED
#define SISWA_H_INCLUDED

struct ALaptop{
    char tipe[255];
};

struct ILaptop {
    char merek[255];
    ALaptop anak;
};

struct TNode {
    ILaptop induk;
    TNode *next;
    TNode *prev;
    TNode *up;
    TNode *down;
};

struct List {
    TNode *head;
    TNode *tail;
};

void insert_induk(List *&list_,TNode *&Ilaptop);
void delete_induk(List *list_,char cari[]);
void insert_anak(TNode *&C,TNode *Ilaptop);
void insert_anak2(List *list_,char cari[]);
TNode* create_induk(char merek[]);
TNode* create_anak(char tipe[]);
void view(List *list_);
int Empty(List *list_);
void createList(List *list_);

#endif // SISWA_H_INCLUDED



#include "siswa.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insert_induk(List *&list_,TNode *&Ilaptop){
    char p;
    char tipe[255];
    if (Empty(list_)==1){
        Ilaptop=list_->head;
        Ilaptop=list_->tail;
    }
    else{
        list_->head->prev=Ilaptop;
        Ilaptop->next=list_->head;
        list_->head=Ilaptop;
    }
    TNode *bantu=Ilaptop;
    cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop? (y/n) : ";
    cin>>p;
    while(p=='y'||p=='Y'){
        cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop : ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(tipe,sizeof tipe);
        insert_anak(bantu,create_anak(tipe));
        cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop lagi? (y/n) : ";
        cin>>p;
    }
}

void insert_anak(TNode *&C,TNode *Ilaptop){
    C->down=Ilaptop;
    Ilaptop->up=C;
    C=Ilaptop;
}

void insert_anak2(List *list_,char cari[]){
    TNode *bantu;
    char tipe[255];
    char p;
    bantu=list_->head;
    if (Empty(list_)==0){
        while (bantu!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(bantu->induk.merek,cari)==0){
                TNode *bantu10=bantu;
                cout<<"Merek Laptop "<<bantu->induk.merek<<endl<<endl;
                cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop : ";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(tipe,sizeof tipe);
                insert_anak(bantu10,create_anak(tipe));
                cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop lagi? (y/n) : ";
                cin>>p;
                while(p=='y'||p=='Y'){
                    cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop : ";
                    cin.ignore();
                    cin.getline(tipe,sizeof tipe);
                    insert_anak(bantu10,create_anak(tipe));
                    cout<<"masukkan tipe laptop lagi? (y/n) : ";
                    cin>>p;
                }
            }
            else {
                bantu=bantu->next;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Data tidak ada!";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Data masih kosong";
    }
}

void delete_induk(List *list_,char cari[]){
    TNode *bantu,*bantu2,*bantu3;
    bantu=list_->head;
    if (Empty(list_)==0){
        while (bantu!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(bantu->induk.merek,cari)==0){
                bantu3=bantu;
                bantu3->prev->next=bantu->next;
                bantu->next->prev=bantu3;
                while (bantu!=NULL) {
                    bantu2=bantu;
                    bantu=bantu->down;
                    delete bantu2;
                }
                return;
            }
            else {
                bantu=bantu->next;
            }
        }
        cout<<"Data tidak ada!";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Data masih kosong";
    }
}


TNode* create_induk(char merek[]){
    TNode *baru=new TNode;
    baru->next=NULL;
    baru->prev=NULL;
    baru->up=NULL;
    baru->down=NULL;
    strcpy(baru->induk.merek,merek);
    return baru;
}

TNode* create_anak(char tipe[]){
    TNode *baru=new TNode;
    baru->next=NULL;
    baru->prev=NULL;
    baru->up=NULL;
    baru->down=NULL;
    strcpy(baru->induk.anak.tipe,tipe);
    return baru;
}

void view(List *list_){
    TNode *bantu2;
    TNode *bantu=list_->head;
    if (Empty(list_)==0){
        while(bantu!=NULL){
            cout<<"| ";
            bantu2=bantu->down;
            while(bantu2!=NULL){
                cout<<bantu2->induk.anak.tipe<<" | ";
                bantu2=bantu->down;
            }
            bantu=bantu->next;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Data masih kosong";
    }
}

int Empty(List *list_){
    if (list_->head==NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void createList(List *list_){
    list_->head=NULL;
    list_->tail=NULL;
}



#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "siswa.h"

using namespace std;



int main()
{
List *B;
int pil;
char merk[255];
TNode *induk;
createList(B);
menu:
cout<<"1. Tambah Merek Laptop\n2. Tambah Tipe Laptop\n3. Hapus Merek Laptop beserta tipe nya\n4. View seluruh Laptop\nMasukkan pilihan : ";
cin>>pil;

    switch (pil){
        case 1: cout<<"Masukkan Merek Laptop : ";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(merk,sizeof merk);
                induk=create_induk(merk);
                insert_induk(B,induk);
                getch();
                goto menu;
        case 2: cout<<"Masukkan Merek Laptop yang ingin ditambahkan Tipe nya : ";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(merk,sizeof merk);
                insert_anak2(B,merk);
                getch();
                goto menu;
        case 3: cout<<"Masukkan Merek Laptop yang ingin dihapus : ";
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(merk,sizeof merk);
                delete_induk(B,merk);
                getch();
                goto menu;
        case 4: view(B);
                getch();
                goto menu;
        default:getch();
                goto menu;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i really have no idea where is the problem, wrong algoritm?

Comment: All "build runs fine" means is that there are no syntax errors. It does not check for, e.g., inappropriate memory accesses, uses of uninitialized values, etc. That needs to be done via debugger.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please do not dump your code and ask others to debug it for you. Before you begin, **eliminate all warnings**. Don't ask people to do the job that a compiler can do better than them. Next, a good rule of thumb is to limit your code to the amount that does not require scrolling, although there are definitely exceptions to this rule. Try removing some code to get a portion of your expected behavior. If you get stuck with a smaller program, it would be easier to get meaningful debugging help with it. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
List* B;
```

Change this line to following;

```
List* B = new List();
```

Hope this helps.